# Possibility of installing php memcache extension from the official repositories?

Tags: php, memcached, redhat, pecl

My question is just a yes/no . Although I have read about the installation of php-memcache extension on a lot of web sites, I just want to confirm whether there is any possibility to install the memcache extension from the official repositories ? i.e. not from PECL. My question may seem little weird but I will appreciate a straight forward answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php extension memcache can be installed through php-pecl-memcache package from the yum repositories.

> yum install php-pecl-memcache

seems to do the trick :)